# How to wait for the powershell commands to run in node-powershell before moving ahead?

Tags: node.js, powershell

I am making a package for atom using javascript. I want to interpret a python code file using node-powershell before the program moves ahead. How do I ensure that all the powershell commands have finished before the moving ahead?

I have tried using ps.dispose() but even this is running before the powershell commands have ended.

```
function run_powershell(callback){

        console.log("powershell started");
        let ps = new shell({
            executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
            noProfile: true
        });

        ps.addCommand('cd '+ __dirname)
        ps.addCommand('python python_output.py')
        ps.addCommand('exit')
        ps.invoke()
        .then(output => {
            console.log(output);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        ps.dispose()
        .then(function(){
          console.log("inside dispose");
          callback();
        });
        console.log("powershell has ended");
      }
```

The output I am getting is:
"powershell started"
"powershell ended"
"inside dispose"

the output I want to get is:
"powershell started"
"inside dispose"
"powershell ended"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You might want to integrate `Start-Sleep`,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep?view=powershell-6) even just a few milliseconds may make the difference.

To save you some time I integrated it into the code at the place I thought appropriate:

```
console.log("powershell started");
let ps = new shell({
    executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
    noProfile: true
});

ps.addCommand('cd '+ __dirname)
ps.addCommand('python python_output.py')
ps.addCommand('exit')
ps.invoke()
.then(output => {
    console.log(output);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
ps.dispose()
.then(function(){
  console.log("inside dispose");
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
  callback();
});
console.log("powershell has ended");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell have a "wait" parameter you may be able to use in your code. When running a script or .exe file it would look something like this in the powershell console:

```
PowerShell.exe -command Script.ps1 -noprofile -nonewwindow **-Wait**
```

Also, the command Start-process have a "-wait" parameter,

```
Start-Process -FilePath "executible" -ArgumentList "args" **-Wait** -NoNewWindow
```

Hope you can use any of this!

Comment: I do not find a `-Wait` switch on he `powershell.exe` command.